# Unresolved reference getInstance

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, mvvm

I'm trying to create an app that allows authentication via firebase according to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIuHATUBGvA).Unfortunately, when writing the code for the AppModule.kt file, there is a problem with specifying the getInstance function for FirebaseAuth.

[this is my AppModule.kt code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHvak.png)

I searched for a solution on the Internet, unfortunately I did not find it.

Comment: Going forward, please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the wrong class. You should import FirebaseAuth from the firebase package.